# open "shape" attribute in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, gis, shapefile, geo

I am doing a road network project. I want to obtain each segment's GPS coordination. I just converted shape file data to mysql database and there is an attribute called `SHAPE` and it is "geometry" type. I tried to

```
select SHAPE from table
```

and the output is messy.

Does anyone know how to open this "geometry" typed SHAPE attribute?

I also want to know if shape file is the right one to use because there is another type of data: geodatabase. Which one is better if I want to extract road network data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql supports several geometry functions for editing and querying spatial data. 
See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-function-reference.html) for the full list

Some example:

```
-- show the WKT representation of the geometry
SELECT ST_AsText(SHAPE) FROM table;
-- show the coordinates of start and end point of the lines
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_StartPoint(SHAPE)), ST_AsText(ST_EndPoint(SHAPE)) FROM table;
-- show how many points build the line
SELECT ST_NumPoints(SHAPE)) FROM table;
-- length of the lines
SELECT ST_Length(SHAPE)) FROM table;
```

If you need all coordinates of your lines, you can simply parse the result of the `ST_AsText(SHAPE)` query.
Alternatively, I would recommend this workflow:

1) Query the number of the points of each line with the function `ST_NumPoints(SHAPE)`

2) iterate over 1 and the number of points and use the function `ST_X(ST_PointN(SHAPE, n))` and `ST_Y(ST_PointN(SHAPE, n))` to get the coordinates of the actual point, where `n` is the actual number

The iteration can you implement in a mysql stored procedure or a external program or script.

See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/gis-linestring-property-functions.html) for linestring specific functions.

**Geodatabase OR Shapefile?**
You are currently using neither shapefile nor geodatabase, but MySql. If you only want to import network data in a database, shapefile are ok. On the other hand, with geodatabase you could probably better work in ArcGis, without using external tools.

If you want to use a external database, I would recommend you to import the shape file in PostgreSQL and not in MySql, since it has a more powerful support for spatial data.

Comment: Thank you so much Tommaso! Very helpful!! Can I ask if the "lines" means a road segment? why does one line have many points on it? is it just for accurate visualization? or the points are physical road intersection?

Comment: Or I should ask how to find the gps coordinates of all intersections?

Comment: A segment is a part of a line that is bounded by two distinct end points. Also, a line with 2 points is composed of only 1 segment, a line with 3 points is composed of 2 segments and so on. I don't know if you imported all segments in one single line or more lines or even in many single segment lines, so my answer is generic.